# How to build Plot Histogram in R with multiple variables?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Anyone help me to build histogram of this dataset?

`dat2 <- data.frame(mean_setosa, mean_versicolor, mean_virginica)`

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxFnh.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `barplot`:

```r
d <- aggregate(Petal.Length~Species, data = iris, FUN = mean)

     Species Petal.Length
1     setosa        1.462
2 versicolor        4.260
3  virginica        5.552


barplot(Petal.Length~Species, data = d)
```

[image]

Using the `ggplot2` graphical package, you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for youe answer, I did the same you advise but there is an error `Error in barplot.default(Species ~ Petal.Length, data = d) : 
  'height' must be a vector or a matrix`

Comment: You inverted `Species` and `Petal.Length`. Please carefully check that you copied the code I provided as it is.

Comment: I got it, Thank you very much!